# Check if there are more elements to come in $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `$.each()` method of jQuery to loop over a couple of objects. Is there a way to find out if there are more objects to come in the `$.each()` method?

Something like:

```
$.each(data, function(o, myObject) {
    if(data.hasMoreObjects) {
        // append something 
    } else {
        // append nothing
    }
});
```

Comment: So mean.. are you currently on the last key/value property of the object that `.each` will act upon?

Comment: You need to know something like if it's the last element?

Comment: Yep that would provide what I need.

Comment: You say `data` is an object -- as in a dictionary with key/value pairs, or an Array?

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to re-implement `Array#join`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument passed to the callback function is the `index`. You can compare this to the `length` to determine if there are more elements.

```
$.each(data, function(index, myObject) {
    if (index === (data.length - 1)) {
        // this is the last
    } else {
        // there are more coming
    }
});
```

Depending on what `data` is, you may need to use some other property in place of `data.length`. For example, if `data` is an object, you would use `Object.keys(data).length`,

[docs for $.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [docs for Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: Object.size? What JS implementation has this?

Comment: @GGG it's a shim function since some browsers do not support `Object.keys`. See the docs link.

Comment: @GGG did you even look at the link or are you just intent on bothering me? :P

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the link. That's not a shim, and those aren't docs =/ It's hardly appropriate to act as if Object.size is some built-in thing as you're doing here.

Comment: Thanks @jbabey, exactelly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to go the other way around. For instance, if you have:

```
a b c d
```

And you want to insert `|` between them, you might do it like this:

```
a| b| c| d
```

In other words, by looping through and adding a `|` to all but the last. But it would be easier to work differently for the first:

```
a |b |c |d
```

Because you can do this:

```
var isfirst = true;
$.each(data, function(o, myObject) {
    if( isfirst) {
        isfirst = false;
    }
    else {
        // do something
    }
});
```

However, if this is not possible, you may have to loop once to count the elements (unless it's an array rather than an object, in which case `.length` will do fine), then add an iterator to your loop.

Answer (score 3):

All of the other answers seem to assume that `data` is an *Array* (or has some property `.length`) but according to the [jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), you can use `$.each` on any *Object*.

Here is a way to get the last [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) key of an object

```
function lastKey(o) {
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    return keys[keys.length-1];
}
```

You could then compare against this in your `$.each`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var howmany = data.length,
    i = 1;
$.each(data, function(o, myObject) {
    if(i == howmany) {
        // do something with the last
    }
    else {
        // do something with the others
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

compare the index with the length od data object,,

try this

```
$.each(data, function(index, myObject) {
 if (index === (data.length - 1)) {
    //append nothing     } else {
    // append something
 }
});
```